# What ecommerce is this?

Tags: ecommerce

Hi just out of curiosity, does anyone what cart does this store http://goo.gl/WqnyC uses? It's nothing like Magento, Opencart or Wordpress + cart? And it looks really nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that very possibly, can be mangento enterprise "paid" version and the owner of the store just removed all mention of it.

http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com/

Comment: thanks Mohamed Anis, ah magento enterprise. never crossed my mind. it looks awesome and neat. thanks for the info

Comment: you are most welcome !

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything. What you're seeing is just a nicely done front-end. It's quite likely that it's a custom built application or one built by a company for their own use.

The front-end appearance of the site has little to do with the platform it was built on.

As Mohamed Anis Dahmani says, if the site was built with a publicly available Ecommerce/CMS then the site's builder may have simply removed anything that gives away what it was built with.